# Microservices With CosmosDB on Azure

Tags: azure, microservices, azure-cosmosdb

I've read a bit about microservices and the favored approach appears to be a separate database for each microservice.  With regards to Azure's CosmosDB, would that mean a separate Table for each service?  What's the best way to architect this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a huge variety of factors to consider here which ultimately means there is no right answer to this question and it will be very specific to the nature of the application you're trying to build. As such, broad statements attempting to offer "general" advice and patterns should be taken with a huge grain of salt. With Cosmos a few of the many high level things to consider when making your decisions are as follows:

**Partitioning**: Cosmos collections support almost infinite scale based on the selection of an appropriate partition key. So, for example you could have a single collection and separate your services such that they each write to a distinct partition key. This would provide you with a form of service multi-tenancy which might be perfectly appropriate for your particular application. However, throughput is also scaled at the collection level so if certain services have much higher read and/or write requirements this may not work for you and could be an indication that that particular service should use it's own collection which can be scaled independently.

**Cost**: You're billed per collection with a minimum throughput requirement. Depending on the number and nature of your micro services this could result in exponentially higher costs for little gain.

**Isolation**: Again, depending on the nature of your application you might have a hard business requirement that data from different services be physically separate from each other which would force you to use separate collections.

The point that I'm trying to make here is that there is absolutely no right answer to this question. You need to weight the pros/cons very carefully in the context of the solution you are trying to build and select the approach that is right for you.

Comment: My application is a simple recipe application which contains a recipe table and a users table (and some basic supporting tables).

Comment: It doesn't sound like using the Table API is a good choice for your application. Table API basically only allows you to query on PartitionKey and Id. Wouldn't you also like to be able to query on actual properties of your recipes, users, etc? The regular Document API would be a much better choice.

Comment: I'll look into that, thank you.  I was under the impression that you could store entities that look like classes you define.

Comment: @TrevorBrooks You can definitely put entities that look like classes into Cosmos using the Table APIs. It's querying on the properties later that is difficult if you choose to go that route

Comment: Since the document database foundation of CosmosDB doesn't really have a concept of tables, I would simulate that by saying that each microservice owns a set of types and only that microservice can directly access those types. The others have to go through the owner microservice to access them.

Comment: @LarryMaccherone I would definitely agree with this as a potentially suitable approach for the app being described